# I am having trouble with repeating user inputs when dealing try-catch statements

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am making a program which asks a user whether they want to calculate Distance, speed or time and then depending on the answer the program asks the user to input the values and does the calculation. I am struggling with getting the program to repeat if the incorrect value is given.

```js
//This program asks the user to input whether they would like to calculate distance, time or     speed.
//Depending their answer they get asked to input the values of the other two options
//The program then calculates either the speed, distance or time
//it is in a try incase that there is an error
try {
  let question = prompt("Would you like to calculate Distance(km), Time(h) or Speed(kph)");
  let answer = question.toLowerCase();
  if (answer === "distance") {
    let time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
    let speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
    let calculation = speed * time;
    console.log(`The Distance is: ${calculation} km`);
  } else if (answer === "time") {
    let distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
    speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
    let calculation2 = distance / speed;
    console.log(`Your Time is: ${calculation2} hours`);
  } else if (answer === "speed") {
    distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
    time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
    calculation3 = distance / time;
    console.log(`Your speed is: ${calculation3} kph`)
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log("The code did not run properly. You did not enter the correct value.")
  question = prompt("Would you like to calculate Distance(km), Time(h) or Speed(kph)");
  answer = question.toLowerCase();

}
```

Comment: You need a loop to repeat

Comment: You can call the same function itself(as recursive function) if the input value is incorrect.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+a+prompt+until+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code in a function and call the function again if error occurred( Recursion )..( you can provide end option also )

### Sample code

```js
function calculate() {
  try {
    let question = prompt("Would you like to calculate Distance(km), Time(h) or Speed(kph)");
    let answer = question.toLowerCase();
    if (answer === "distance") {
      let time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
      let speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
      let calculation = speed * time;
      console.log(`The Distance is: ${calculation} km`);
    } else if (answer === "time") {
      let distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
      speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
      let calculation2 = distance / speed;
      console.log(`Your Time is: ${calculation2} hours`);
    } else if (answer === "speed") {
      distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
      time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
      calculation3 = distance / time;
      console.log(`Your speed is: ${calculation3} kph`)
    } else {
      calculate();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    calculate();
  }
}
calculate();
```

Comment: Next time click the `[<>]` to make a [mcve]. Your code was poorly formatted so the missing `}` was not easy to spot